# Relation between AlarmManager and INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

Tags: android, performance, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-multiple-users

We recently integrated with Crashlytics in Firebase and found that our app was facing this crash:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
get application info: Neither user 1010170 nor current process has 
android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS.
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1540)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1493)
android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set (IAlarmManager.java:214)
android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl (AlarmManager.java:414)
android.app.AlarmManager.set (AlarmManager.java:213)
```

The code that is causing this is:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (pendingIntent != null) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+triggerAfterMillis,
                pendingIntent);
```

I have tried searching for this in various different places and forums but couldn't get anything fruitful yet.

Could anybody help me establish a relation between **AlarmManager** and **INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS** permission and how to solve this?

**Note:** This is happening majorly on devices running Android 5 and above.

Comment: Did you solve this ? i am also getting this...